# How to stop ordering of keys when ng-repeat is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a bunch of fields mapped as below,

```
$scope.mapfields = {
    ABC: 'Same',
    CBA: 'Cent',
    CLSN: 'Abcde'
  };
```

And then on front end i have the below code,

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in fields">
                            <div class="active compact title">
                                <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                                <b><span ng-bind="mapping[key]"></span></b>
                            </div>
```

So now the ng-repeat is actually sorting the fields which i don't want, how can I achive that. Please help me on this.

FYI - I'm using angular 1.5.0 beta 2 and the above fields are facets

Comment: it's... an object...

Comment: You cannot sort an object!

Comment: Actually, those are columns in db and on front end we are having dropdowns with the unique values of that particular columns, so in db there is column titled "ABC" and on front end we are re-naming it to "Same" and then populating all the unique values from that field in the dropdown

Comment: stored... in an object. with keys that have no guaranteed sort order.

Comment: @tymeJV I'm not sorting but it's still sorting and picking up the position of columns randomly rather than in the line that is specified above, please guide me on how to fix this

Comment: The sorting is coming from the browser. Objects are unsorted - browser A could render them completely different than brower B - you need an array.

Comment: @tymeJV any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: There isn't a fix - it's the design of the language. You need to make an array.

Answer (score 1):

ECMA Specification states that:

> An object is a member of the type Object. It is an **unordered
>   collection of properties** each of which contains a primitive value,
>   object, or function.

In other word, as other have mentioned, object is unordered and the rendering is based on browser implementation.

Here are the workaround.
JSFiddle link: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11263/)

```
      <div ng-repeat="key in keys(mapfields)">
        <div class="active compact title">
          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          <b><span ng-bind="mapfields[key]"></span></b>
        </div>
      </div>

  $scope.mapfields = {
    ABC: 'Same',
    CBA: 'Cent',
    CLSN: 'Abcde'
  };

  $scope.keys = function(obj) {
    return obj ? Object.keys(obj) : [];
  }
```